# ¿Cómo puedo hacer el envió de un formulario que tiene dos input tipo FILE?

Tags: php, html, formularios, archivo

necesito enviar este formulario con PHP dentro del formulario constan dos inputs tipo file el uno lo uso para enviar un documento obligatorio, el otro en caso de que activen el botón de enviar otro documento se abre ese input file.
En el archivo PHP que tengo solo funciona y me llega perfectamente el primer archivo pero no se como hacer para enviar el otro intente de la forma que adjunto pero no se que estoy realizando mal o que necesito hacer para poder enviar esos dos input tipo FILE.

**FORM.HTML**

```
<form action="envio.php" id="formulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
        <h2 class="titulo">Envío de documentos</h2>
        <h3 class="subtitulo">
          Todos los campos marcados con (*) son obligatorios
          si no los llenas no podrás enviar el formulario.
        </h3>

        <input type="text" id="idd" name="idd" hidden>

        <p>N° Documento</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="idDocumento"
          id="idDocumento"
          style="background-color: #dfdfdf;"
          readonly='readonly'
        />
  

        <p>(*) Nombres:</p>
        <p id="p_nombre"></p>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="nombres"
          placeholder="Ej. David Alexander"
          required
        />

        <p>(*) Apellidos:</p>
        <p id="p_apellidos"></p>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="apellidos"
          placeholder="Ej. Banda Llanganate"
          required
        />

        <p>(*) Cédula:<div id="salida"></div></p>
        <p id="p_cedula"></p>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="cedula"
          placeholder="Ej. 050xxxxxxx"
          id="ced"
          onchange="validarCed()"
          required
        />

        <p>(*) Cantón:</p>
        <div class="form-group">                                               
              <select name="Canton" id="Canton"  data-placeholder="- Seleccione un cantón -"
               class="form-control chosenCanton" onchange="change(this.id, 'parroquia')"
               value="<%= typeof Canton != 'undefined' ? Canton : '' %>" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="La Mana">La Maná</option>
               <option value="Latacunga">Latacunga</option>
               <option value="Pangua">Pangua</option>
               <option value="Pujilí">Pujilí</option>
               <option value="Salcedo">Salcedo</option>
               <option value="Saquisili">Saquisilí</option>
               <option value="Sigchos">Sigchos</option>
              </select>
        </div>

        <p>(*) Parroquias:</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select id="parroquia" name="Parroquia" data-placeholder="- Seleccione una parroquia -"
            class="form-control chosenParroquia" value="<%= typeof Parroquia != 'undefined' ? Parroquia : '' %>" required>
              <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <p>(*) Barrio/Comunidad/Recinto:</p>
        <p id="p_barrio"></p>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="barrio"
          placeholder="Ej. Centro"
          required
        /> 

        <p>(*) Dirección Calles:</p>
        <p id="p_direccion"></p>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="direccion"
          placeholder="Ej. Calle Juan Manuel Lasso"
          required
        /> 

        <p>(*) Teléfono Celular:</p>
        <p id="p_t_celular"></p>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="t_celular"
          value="09"
          placeholder="Ej. 09xxxxxxxx"
          required
        /> 

        <p>Teléfono Convencional:</p>
        <p id="p_t_convencional"></p>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="t_convencional"
          id="t_convencional"
          value="03"
          onchange="validarTC()"
          placeholder="Ej. 032xxxxxx"
        />

        <p>(*) Tipo de persona:</p>
        <select name="tipo_persona" class="tipo_persona" required>
          <option value="opcion" selected>Seleccione el tipo de persona...</option>
          <option value="Persona Natural">Persona Natural</option>
          <option value="Persona Jurídica de Derecho Privado">Persona Jurídica de Derecho Privado</option>
          <option value="Persona Jurídica de Derecho Público">Persona Jurídica de Derecho Público</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <p>(*) Correo Electrónico:</p>
        <p id="p_email"></p>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Ej. user@example.com"
          required
        />

        <p>(*) Petición Concreta:</p>
        <!--<input
          type="textarea"
          name="desc"
          placeholder="Documento para..."
          required
        />-->

        <textarea name="desc" id="desc" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Documento para..." required></textarea>

        <p>(*) Archivo Digital PDF:</p>
        <p id="p_file"></p>
        <input
          type="file"
          name="file"
          id="archivoInput"
          onchange="return validarExt()"
          required
        />

        <p>(*) ¿Tiene un archivo adjunto?</p>
        <div id="checkbox">
          <div id="sidiv">
            <span>Si</span><input type="radio" name="si" value="Si" id="si" onclick="ver()"><br>
          </div>
          <div id="nodiv">
            <span>No</span><input type="radio" name="no" value="No" id="no" checked onclick="ocultar()"><br>
          </div>
          
          
        </div>

        
        <div id="show" style="display: none;">
          <p>(*) Archivo Adjunto PDF:</p>
          <p id="p_file2"></p>
          <input
            type="file"
            name="file2"
            id="archivoInput2"
            onchange="return validarExt2()"
          />
        </div>
        

        <input
          type="submit"
          name="next"
          class="next action-button"
          value="Enviar"
          id="btnsubmit"
        />

        <p id="mensaje"></p>
        <p id="mensaje_telefono_con"></p>
       <div id="visorArchivo"></div>
       <div id="visorArchivoAdjunto"></div>
      </fieldset>
      <br />
      <br />
      
    </form>
```

**ENVIO.PHP**

```
<?php

// variables del formulario
    $NDocumento = $_POST['idDocumento'];
    $nombres = strip_tags($_POST['nombres']);
    $apellidos = strip_tags($_POST['apellidos']);
    $cedula = strip_tags($_POST['cedula']);
    $Canton = strip_tags($_POST['Canton']);
    $Parroquia = strip_tags($_POST['Parroquia']);
    $barrio = strip_tags($_POST['barrio']);
    $direccion = strip_tags($_POST['direccion']);
    $t_celular = strip_tags($_POST['t_celular']);
    $t_convencional = strip_tags($_POST['t_convencional']);
    $tipo_persona = strip_tags($_POST['tipo_persona']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $desc = strip_tags($_POST['desc']);

    $asunto2 = 'RECEPCIÓN EXTERNA';

    //ARCHIVO
    $nameFile = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $sizeFile = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $typeFile = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    

    $fecha= time();
    $fechaFormato = date("j/n/Y",$fecha);

    $correoDestino = "user@example.com";
    
    //asunto del correo
    $asunto = "Nuevo documento de: " . $nombres;

    
    // -> mensaje en formato Multipart MIME
    $cabecera = "MIME-VERSION: 1.0\r\n";
    $cabecera .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed;";
    //$cabecera .="boundary='=P=A=L=A=B=R=A=Q=U=E=G=U=S=T=E=N='"
    $cabecera .="boundary=\"=C=T=E=C=\"\r\n";
    $cabecera .= "From: RECEPCIÓN EXTERNA<{$email}>";

    //Primera parte del cuerpo del mensaje
    $cuerpo = "--=C=T=E=C=\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    //cuerpo .= "charset=utf-8\r\n";
    //$cuerpo .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n"; // línea vacía
    $cuerpo .= "Correo enviado por: " . $nombres;
    $cuerpo .= " con fecha: " . $fechaFormato . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "N Documento: " . $NDocumento . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Nombres: " . $nombres . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Apellidos: " . $apellidos . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Cédula: " . $cedula . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Cantón: " . $Canton . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Parroquia: " . $Parroquia . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Barrio: " . $barrio . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Dirección: " . $direccion . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Celular: " . $t_celular . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Covencional: " . $t_convencional . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Tipo de persona: " . $tipo_persona . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Correo: " . $email . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Petición concreta: " . $desc . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n";// línea vacía

    // -> segunda parte del mensaje (archivo adjunto)
        //    -> encabezado de la parte
    $cuerpo .= "--=C=T=E=C=\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ";
    $cuerpo .= "name=" . $nameFile . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
    $cuerpo .= "filename=" . str_replace(' ', '',$nameFile) . "\r\n";  //quito los espacios en el nombre
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n"; // línea vacía
    
    $fp = fopen($tempFile, "rb");
    $file = fread($fp, $sizeFile);
    $file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));
    
    $cuerpo .= "$file\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n"; // línea vacía
    // Delimitador de final del mensaje.
    $cuerpo .= "--=C=T=E=C=--\r\n";
    
    if (!empty($_FILES['file2'])){
        $nameFile2 = $_FILES['file2']['name'];
        $sizeFile2 = $_FILES['file2']['size'];
        $typeFile2 = $_FILES['file2']['type'];
        $tempFile2 = $_FILES['file2']['tmp_name'];
        
    }
    
    //ARCHIVO ADJUNTO 2
    $cuerpo .= "--=C=T=E=C=\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ";
    $cuerpo .= "name=" . $nameFile2 . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
    $cuerpo .= "filename=" . str_replace(' ', '',$nameFile2) . "\r\n";  //quito los espacios en el nombre
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n"; // línea vacía*/
    
    //FILE2
    $fp2 = fopen($tempFile2, "rb");
    $file2 = fread($fp2, $sizeFile2);
    $file2 = chunk_split(base64_encode($file2));
    
    //FILE 2
    $cuerpo .= "$file2\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n"; // línea vacía
    // Delimitador de final del mensaje.
    $cuerpo .= "--=C=T=E=C=--\r\n";
    
    
    //Enviar el correo
    if(mail($correoDestino, $asunto, $cuerpo, $cabecera)){
        echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Documento enviado con exito");window.location.href="formulario.html"</script>';
        
    }else{
        echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Documento no enviado algo fallo!");window.location.href="formulario.html"</script>';
    }
```

Este es hasta el momento mi progreso me llega correctamente el primer documento del primer input pero del segundo no no se que debo hacer estoy atascado en ese punto desde ya agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Quizas estes accediendo mal al arreglo donde esta el file2 , ejecuta un var_dump , y fijate como esta compuesto ese arreglo , para que puedas acceder correctamente .

Comment: Gracias amigo por su recomendación realizare lo que me recomienda aunque por el momento he realizado un echo a las variables que van a darme como resultado el nombre del archivo, tipo de archivo, tamaño y estan todos los datos saliendo de manera correcta pero no se porque al email solo me llega un archivo y el otro no.

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27565430/5587982) tienes un ejemplo funcional para adjuntar múltilpes archivos en un email.